# Is the sequence for the harmonic series in the closed unit ball in l^1?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I wish to show that the closed unit ball in $l^1$ is not compact, for which I believe it would be easiest to show that it is not bounded. For this I want to consider the sequence {1, 1/2, 1/3, ... , 1/n, ...}, since the harmonic series is known to be divergent. But will this sequence actually be in the unit ball of $l^1$? I'm confused by the definition of the norm given to me.

Answer (score 4):

$\ell^1$ is the space of sequences under the norm
$$\left\|x\right\|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_i\right|$$
such that the norm is finite. So no, not only is the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ not in the unit ball, it's not even an element of $\ell^1$ at all.

Answer (score 1):

The closed unit ball in any normed linear space is bounded. Your sequence does not belong to $\ell^{1}$.

To show that that closed unit ball in $\ell^{1}$ is not compact consider the elements $e_n=(0,0,...,0,1,0,0...)$ where $0$ is in the $n-$th place. This is a sequence in this ball with no convergent subsequence: if it all a subsequence converges the limit has to be $(0,0,...)$ (since convergence in $\ell^{1}$ implies convegence of each coordinate) but $\|e_n-(0,0,...)\|=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Alternatively, note that this sequence is not Cauchy, since $||e_{n+1}-e_n||=2$